# Minecraft Modpack error on join

Tags: java, minecraft

I have been trying to create my first modpack using the technic launcher and have run into an issue I can not seem to fix.

My server boots up and gets to the point where you can type commands in it without crashing, and the modpack launches with no issues.

However when I try to connect to the server I get the error

> The following multiparts are not installed on this client:
>   ConduitEnergy0, ConduitEnergy1, ConduitEnergy2, ConduitFluid0,
>   ConduitFluid1, ConduitItem0, ConduitItem1, ConduitItem3,
>   XU:MagnumTorch, extrautils:fence, extrautils:pipe:Jacket............

clientside.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: It has to do with java and modding @August

Answer (score 0):

You need to install those parts that are the in the error. It seems that it can't run without them. Search online for the download.
Hope this solves your problem!

Remember this is a programming forum, and Minecraft questions belong on the Minecraft or technic forums.

Comment: Those parts are installed on both the client and the server, and exist in both of the config files (server and client), that's why I am confused. And I thought since it involved java and since others have posted modpack issues here that it would be appropriate to post this question. @24GHz